# How to use child class depending on parent id in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

### Jquery

```
    $('.arrow').html("˅");
    $('#header_display').click(function() {
        $('#header_diplay .arrow').html("˄");
        $('.header_gadgets').slideToggle("fast");
        if(!$.trim( $('.header_gadgets').html() ).length) {
            $('.header_gadgets').text("This template has no gadgets.");
        }
```

### HTML

```
<li class="list-item" id="header_display">Header<div class="arrow"></div></li>
<li class="list-item" id="sidebar_display">Header<div class="arrow"></div></li>
```

Hi, I am going to make the arrow up and down on toggling div. This is my jquery and html code. In jquery code how can i assign the 'arrow' child class of 'header_display' parent id. After googling I found this in some site but it did not worked for me.

Comment: You're missing `)` at the end of the `click` function call. Is that just a copying error or in the original code?

Comment: I can't figure out what your question means.

Comment: sorry i made mistake while copying my code. But there is closing ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you're missing the last line when copying your code or not but try this.

**Jquery**

```
$('.arrow').html("˅");
$('#header_display').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
    $('#header_display .arrow').html("˄");
  else
    $('#header_display .arrow').html("˅");
  $('.header_gadgets').slideToggle("fast");
  if(!$.trim( $('.header_gadgets').html() ).length) {
    $('.header_gadgets').text("This template has no gadgets.");
  }
});
```

When user clicked on `#header_display`, you change the arrow but then you never change it back. I've added a class to check if it has been clicked or not.

Not sure what's with `.header_gadgets`. I'm ignoring that part.

[See example](http://codepen.io/josephting/pen/pLnjf/).